# How to find all elements that belong to a dynamically added class by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically (by jquery) made HTML elements that have classes `.foo` and `.bar`, whose all elements are `inputs` of type `checkboxes`. I have a button `checkAll` that checks all the boxes and pushes its `id`s into an array called `selectedBuckets`.This button wasn't made dynamically. It looks something like this:

```
var bucketClasses = [$('.foo'), $('.bar')];
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
    var isAdd = true;       
    var selectedBuckets = [];
    bucketClasses.forEach(function (bucketClass) {
        bucketClass.each(function () {
            this.checked = isAdd;
            if (isAdd)
                selectedBuckets.push(this.id);
        })
    });
});
```

The problem is that the function is not able to find out the HTML elements that have a class `.foo` (or `.bar` for that matter). By putting breakpoints, I see that `bucketClass` is an empty array while ideally it should be an array of all the `checkboxes` that have class as `.foo`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also post your HTML please :)

Comment: please look for `live` and `on` jquery api.these methods helps to handle element which are dynamically created

Comment: Move the line `var bucketClasses = [$('.foo'), $('.bar')];` inside the click handler so that it gets the elements that _currently_ have those classes. Although the code seems rather more complicated than it needs to be. Rather than a nested loop can't you just say `selectedBuckets = $('.foo,.bar').prop('checked',true).map(function() { return this.id; }).get();`

Comment: @nnnnnn While debugging, I try printing the `bucketClasses`. It seems to be allright and print the array correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your var in the click's callback function:

```
$('#checkAll').click(function () {
    var bucketClasses = [$('.foo'), $('.bar')];
    // all other code as is
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff i just suggested a slight change of var although your selector is quite readable and in the above comments a comment by _nnnnnn_ is much better.

Comment: While debugging, I try printing the `bucketClasses`. It seems to be allright and print the array correctly.